# How to Animate Bar Chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am new to d3.js. I created this bar chart watching a YouTube tutorial.

[image: bar chart]

I want to animate my chart [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJksL53XGRE) there is no video on youtube for doing animation like that. I want to animate the population horizontally and move regions up or down based on their count.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are plenty of examples online, outside youtube. The bonus over a video is that you can copy/paste code.